Tengo Astro y Tailwind, en el Dark/light mode no puedo agregarle tiempo de transición a un fondo con "bg-gradient-to-r"
Estimados tengo la siguiente configuración.
tailwind.config.inf
  content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [animations],
};

layout.astro

<body class="dark:bg-gray-900">  

    <div
      class="absolute inset-0 -z-20 h-full w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-300 to-blue-500 dark:bg-gradient-to-r dark:from-cyan-900 dark:to-blue-900 "
    >
    </div>

    <Header />
    <slot />
  </body>

El código anterior funciona pero al agregarle la transición no lo hace.
transition-all animate-delay-1000

Pero al agregarla al div no me funciona.
El cambio se esta haciendo con un toggle en JS q hace bien el trabajo.
Y al poner un color como el siguiente
bg-orange-400

funciona la transición correctamente pero al poner un degradado no me funciona la transición.
